Issues with computing an integral
I was studying a paper for my economics class and encountered the following integral.
I just need to define a couple of concepts to make the question clearer, but it is primarily about mathematics. You can skip the economic concepts and go straight to the section flagged as  MATH below if needed.
\begin{equation}
L_t = P_t \left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} h_t (1 - \phi n_t) \, d F_t(h_t) -
\int_{0}^{\infty} e_t n_t \bar{h}_t \, dF_t (h_t)  \right]
\end{equation}
where $F_t(h_t)$ is the distribution function of human capital, $F_t(h)$, evolves according to:
\begin{equation}
 F_{t+1}(h) = \frac{P_t}{P_{t+1}} \int_{0}^{\infty} n_t \mathbb{I}(h_{t+1} \le h) \, dF_t(h_t).
 \label{cdf_h}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{I}$ is an indicator function.
Average human capital $\bar{h}_t$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
\bar{h}_t = \int_{0}^{\infty} h_t d F_t (h_t)
\end{equation}
Now, when the paper studies the balanced growth path (the trajectory such that all variables grow at a constant rate), the distribution of relative human capital levels (defined as $x_t \equiv h_t / \bar{h_t})$ is
\begin{equation}
G_t(x_t) \equiv F_t\left(x_t \bar{h}_t \right)
\end{equation}
MATH
Now, from the first equation, if you divide both sides by $P_t \bar{h}_t$, you get,
\begin{equation}
\frac{L_t}{P_t \bar{h}_t} =  \left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} x_t (1 - \phi n_t) \, d G_t(x_t) -
\int_{0}^{\infty} e_t n_t  \, dG_t (x_t)  \right]
\label{clear_mod}
\end{equation}
Now, we are integrating across $x_t$. Thus, we must recognize that for $x_t \in (0, \frac{\theta}{\eta \phi}]$, and thus
\begin{equation}
e_t=0, \, n_t = \frac{\gamma }{ \phi (1+ \beta + \gamma)}
\end{equation}
and for $x_t > \frac{\theta}{\eta \phi}$, and thus,
\begin{equation}
e_t = \frac{\eta \phi x_t - \theta}{1-\eta}, \,
n_t = \frac{(1-\eta) \gamma x_t }{(\phi x_t -\theta) (1+ \beta + \gamma)}
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  \frac{L_t}{P_t \bar{h}_t} = & \int_{0}^{\frac{\theta}{\eta \phi}} 
  \left[  x_t \left(1 - \phi  \frac{\gamma }{ \phi (1+ \beta + \gamma)} \right) \right] \, d G_t(x_t)  \\
  & + \int_{\frac{\theta}{\eta \phi}}^{\infty} 
  \left[  x_t \left(1 - \phi  \frac{\gamma (1-\eta) }{ \phi (1+ \beta + \gamma)} \right) \right] \, d G_t(x_t) \\
  & - \int_{0}^{\frac{\theta}{\eta \phi}} 
  \left[ 0 \left( \frac{\gamma }{ \phi (1+ \beta + \gamma)} \right) \right]\, d G_t(x_t) \\
  & - \int_{\frac{\theta}{\eta \phi}}^{\infty} 
  \left[ \left( \frac{\eta \phi x_t - \theta}{1-\eta} \right) 
  \left( \frac{(1-\eta) \gamma x_t }{(\phi x_t -\theta) (1+ \beta + \gamma)} \right) 
  \right] \, dG_t(x_t)
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Which some simplification,
\begin{equation}
\frac{L_t}{P_t \bar{h}_t} = 
\int_0^{\frac{\theta}{\eta \phi}} \frac{(1 + \beta)}{1+ \beta + \gamma} x_t \, dG_t(x_t)
+ \int_{\frac{\theta}{\eta \phi}}^{\infty} 
\left( 1 - \gamma \frac{\phi(1 - \eta) x_t + (\eta \phi x_t - \theta)}{(\phi x_t - \theta)(1 + \beta + \gamma)} \right) x_t \, dG_t(x_t)
\end{equation}
The article states that this sum yields:
\begin{equation}
\frac{L_t}{P_t \bar{h}_t} = \frac{1+ \beta}{1+ \beta + \gamma}
\end{equation}
Can you show me why this final result holds?
